# Confusion in using templates in class

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

I am currently teaching my self/learning about generic programming and how you can use `templates` to declare a datatype at run time. I understood the basic example where you can make a variable a template so that you can make any data type later on but here is me attempting templates with a class/vector:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T, class U>   
class CMap{ 
private:
    vector<T> keys;
    vector<U> values;

public:
    void insert(T key, U value){
        keys.push_back(key);
        values.push_back(value);
    }

    void get(int n){
        cout << keys[n] << " values ->" << values[n];
    }
};

int main(){
    CMap<string, int> grades;
    grades.insert("Jones", 12);
    grades.insert("Smith", 40);

    grades.get(0);
    cout << endl;
    grades.get(1);
    cout << endl;
}
```

I understand that we created `T` and `U` as a template which will go into the `vector` data type. I also understand we can use the `insert` method dynamically because the `T` and `U` are templates.

What I don't understand:

When I declare my class i have been told to add the following `<string, int>`
I don't understand what this is doing? How does it know that the first parameter should go to `vector<t> keys` and the second parameter inside the `<>` should go to `vector<u> values` - if that is what it is doing?

Comment: Well, you've named them -- the first one is `T`, which receives `string`, and the second one is `U`, which receives `int`.

Comment: "how you can use templates to declare a datatype at run time" What gives you an impression that templates can do that?

Comment: What is confusing? It works like functions and parameters. You have a template, and when you use it, you supply parameters... It is not happening at the run time.

Comment: @luk32 arguments. You supply arguments to parameters. </pedantic> :)

Comment: Yes, yes, my bad, same goes for templates. We declare them with parameters, and use supplying arguments, so that parameters are replaced with arguments. (I hope I got it right =)

Comment: "How does it know that the first paramater should go to vector<t> keys and the second paramater inside the <> should go to vector<u> values - if that is what it is doing?" You have this code: `template <class T, class U> class CMap`. When you say `CMap<string, int>` what do you think should happen? There are two arguments `string` and `int`  in angle brackets, and there are two parameters named `T` and `U` in angle brackets...

Comment: @Quentin but HOW does it know that T should go to string. What if i had like 5 other private variables there and only supplied two arguments in my class instantiation. how does it know which gets matched with what

Comment: @jimmyspinner because your template parameters are `<T, U>`, and you provided the arguments `<string, int>`. They are matched in order one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the statement `CMap<string, int> grades;` you are creating the object of type CMap where each occurrence of `T` gets replaced with `string` and each occurrence of `U` is replaced with `int`.

Since your insert method has the signature `void insert(T key, U value)`, your newly created object will take in a `string` and an `int` to replace `T` and `U` because that's the data type you supplied when creating the object.

You could use whatever data type you like for `T` and `U` including your own classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first clear up what it means to declare a template in C++, as there seems to be some confusion.

#### What a template *is*

A template is something you create a class out of, sort of like a class factory. A template is **not** a class nor a type.

You declare a template and the parameters it will take by `template<class T, class U  /* ... */>`, similar to how a function takes values as arguments.

When you pass in types as template arguments, you *instantiate* the template, thereby creating a type. When a template is instantiated, the type you passed in will replace the occurrences of the same parameter, again, similar to how argument passing works with functions.

```
template<class T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    T member;
};
MyTemplateClass<int> var;
```

In this example `MyTemplateClass` is the template, it is **not** a type.

`MyTemplateClass<int>` *is* a type, having exactly one member variable of type `int`. We say `MyTemplateClass<int>` is an *instantiation* of `MyTemplateClass`. Every occurrence of `T` in `MyTemplateClass` is replaced with `int` in `MyTemplateClass<int>`.

Since `MyTemplateClass<int>` is just a type, the last line is simply a variable declaration, therefore `var` is just a variable of type `MyTemplateClass<int>`.

This all happens at compile-time, **not** run-time.
The compiler knows exactly what `MyTemplateClass<int>` is, and it knows exactly what types are in it, and it knows exactly what the code should compile to.

#### Answering your question

In your case

```
template<class T, class U>
class CMap{ 
private:
    vector<T> keys;
    vector<U> values;
//...
};
```

is really declaring that you have a template that have 2 parameters, and has 2 member variables. `keys` have type `vector<T>` where `T` is the first template parameter, and `values` have type `vector<U>` where `U` is the second template parameter.

```
CMap<string, int> grades;
```

is really declaring a variable `grades` with type `CMap<string, int>`.

`CMap<string, int>` is an instantiation of `CMap` with `string` and `int` as arguments.

`grades.keys` have type `vector<string>` and `grades.values` have type `vector<int>`.

Comment: yes but how does it know that vector<t> keys is matching with class t. what if i had more private variables and i didnt want them to be a template

Comment: @jimmyspinner declare them as is? `int member2`?